# I wrote a program to get the count of matching adjacent alphabets in a string

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, for-loop, string-matching

For the same 1 of the  test cases have passed while all the other had failed. The failed ones test cases were of very long strings. but could not understand where did I go wrong.

The number of test cases and string is been read in the main function, and string gets passed to this function.

```cs
public static int getMaxScore(string jewels)
{
    string temp=jewels;
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<temp.Length-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<temp.Length-1;j++)
        {
            if(jewels[i]==jewels[j+1])
            {
                temp=jewels.Remove(i,2);
                count++;                      
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }    
        }                
    }        
    return count;
}
```

for the passed 1, there were 2 test cases. In that, one being jewels="abcddcbd" and the other being "abcd". Expected Output was 3 for the first string and 0 for the second. however, i got the expected output for this test case. but failed all other ones(those are very long strings)

```
jewels="edmamjboxwzfjsgnmycuutvkhzerdiabcvzlnoazreuavyemxqwgyzdvrzyohamwamziqvdduequyyspfipvigooyqmwllvp"
```

Can somebody help me in knowing what is wrong in my code or how can I obtain the result I want?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: What is the expected output for the input value if jewel? Can you also explain the logic of your code?

Comment: `temp=jewels.Remove(i,2);` means `temp` will be shorter than `jewels`. But your loop is `for(int i=0;i<temp.Length-1;i++)`. The net effect is that when you find adjacent entries you effectively start ignoring the elements at the **end** of `jewels` (where the index is > `temp.Length`).

Comment: `GroupAdjacent` is where I would start. https://morelinq.github.io/2.7/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_GroupAdjacent__2_1.htm

Comment: Should it start from a? or 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' are considered adjacent?

Comment: A regex like ([a-zA-Z])(\1) detected all the 5 matches of consecutive characters in the jewel string.

Comment: For us to help further, what is the expected result for **each** of the following inputs - `abbc` `aabbcc` `aabbaa` `abba` `aaabbbbccccc`?

Comment: "In that, one being jewels="abcddcbd" and the other being "abcd". Expected Output was 3 for the first string and 0 for the second."  I'm still trying to figure out why the first string would return 3...

Comment: @Idle_Mind I suspect the idea is that you remove the adjacent entries, which may then make a _new_ pair adjacent.

Comment: @mjwills Gotcha!  I see that now.  I missed that TWO characters were being removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds a [Jewel Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewel_Quest) puzzle. Checking a string for adjacent equal characters, remove them and increase the counter by 1. Removing the two characters from the string could produce a new one with adjacent equal characters so it must be checked again from the beginning to remove them, increase the counter, and do it all over again until no more.

```cs
public static int getMaxScore(string jewels)
{
    var count = 0;
    var max = jewels.Length;
    var i = 0;
    var chars = jewels.ToList();
    var adj = 2; //<- Change to increase the number of adjacent chars.

    while (i < max)
    {
        if (chars.Count >= adj && i <= chars.Count - adj &&
            chars.Skip(i).Take(adj).Distinct().Count() == 1)
        {
            count++;
            chars.RemoveRange(i, adj);
            max = chars.Count;
            i = 0;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Testing:

```cs
void TheCaller()
{
    Console.WriteLine(getMaxScore("abcddcbd"));
    Console.WriteLine(getMaxScore("abcd"));
    Console.WriteLine(getMaxScore("edmamjboxwzfjsgnmycuutvkhzerdiabcvzlnoazreuavyemxqwgyzdvrzyohamwamziqvdduequyyspfipvigooyqmwllvp"));
}
```

Writes 3, 0, and 5 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static int CountThings(string s)
        {
            if(s.Length < 2) { return 0; }

            int n = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (s[i] == s[i + 1])
                {
                    int start = i;
                    int end = i + 1;
                    while (s[start] == s[end] && start >= 0 && end <= s.Length - 1)
                    {
                        n++;
                        start--;
                        end++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return n;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For grits and shins, here's a compact recursive version:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string jewels = "edmamjboxwzfjsgnmycuutvkhzerdiabcvzlnoazreuavyemxqwgyzdvrzyohamwamziqvdduequyyspfipvigooyqmwllvp";
    int score = getMaxScore(new StringBuilder(jewels));

    Console.WriteLine($"jewels = {jewels}");
    Console.WriteLine($"score = {score}");

    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static int getMaxScore(StringBuilder jewels)
{
    for(int i=0; i<(jewels.Length-1); i++)
        if (jewels[i]==jewels[i+1])
            return 1 + getMaxScore(jewels.Remove(i, 2));
    return 0;
}
```